# Talking/connecting to a secure element applet micro sd on Android?

Tags: java, android, sd-card, android-sdcard

How can I talk/communcated say to a (G&D) micro SD card secure element on Android?

This is WITHOUT flashing or having a custom ROM on the phone - want it to work on Galaxy S2 and S3.

We could do this in BlackBerry and use the Rim 'SmartCardReader' object and once a connection was made then send APDU bytes, but I can't find anything similar in Android to make a connection.
Is there code or a library that allows access to it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following project:

http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/

I have been looking for something similar and this is the closest I've found